# Convert ISO DateTime to Millisecond

Tags: javascript, ios, datetime, isodate

I have an ISODateTime format :

```
2013-11-21T20:58:03+0000
```

How to convert it to milliseconds in AngularJS.

I used DateTime.Parse() => it works on chrome but fails on ios.
Any other way to implement the same?

My main aim for this is to find difference (in minutes) between current time and this time :

```
var diff= (new Date(new Date().getTime() - Date.parse(item['myDate']))).getMinutes();
```

where item['myDate'] = 2013-11-21T20:58:03+0000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be sure that it will work on any browser (like iOS safari) we can just split time and create new date instance.

Try:

```
$scope.item = {};   
$scope.item.myDate = '2013-11-21T20:58:03+0000';

var arr =  $scope.item.myDate.split(/[- :+T]/);
var fixedDate = new Date(arr[0], arr[1]-1, arr[2], arr[3], arr[4]);

var currTime = new Date().getTime();
var fixedTime = fixedDate.getTime();
var tot = currTime -  fixedTime;

var minutes = tot / 1000 / 60;

console.log('tot', tot);
console.log('minutes', minutes);
```

Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/850/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, but it gives NaN... I logged fixedTime = new Date($scope.item.myDate).getTime();
and new Date(item['myDate']).getTime();
Both give NaN too

Comment: Even new Date(item['myDate']) gives NaN

Comment: new Date(item['myDate']) gives Invalid Date

Comment: Try my fix I achanged

Comment: Hi, I was finally able to fix this on IOS by trimming the +FFFF values from the datetime. This allowed for smooth executuion of the entire code. Even your previous fiddle. Thanks a lot..